# Help deciding analyses - RCT

Tags: predictive-models, pre-post-comparison, mancova

I am developing a proposal for an RCT. The IV/treatment has two levels - active control Vs experimental treatment. I plan on measuring EEG ERP baselines as predictor variables for treatment response. Treatment response will be measured by four dependent variables: pre and post treatment PANSS and MCCB scores.

I am unsure as to the best statistical analyses. I could use MANCOVA with the ERP baselines as covariates, or ignore them and perform MANCOVA with pre treatment scores as the covariates, and then do secondary analysis with Pearson correlation for ERP and post treatment scores and change in scores pre to post.

Is this sound reasoning or should I be heading toward a linear regression model? The DVs and ERP data are continuous, the IV is categorical.